# Why does query optimizer not optimize my predicate?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

I was trying to understand the effects of introducing variables in a predicate. I have this query

```
declare @CommentedOnly nvarchar(max)=null

select top 5 * from journalemail je
where @CommentedOnly IS NULL OR je.ID IN (SELECT EmailID FROM EmailComments)
```

And here is the actual plan

[image]

I was hoping that the filter would be optimized and removed as it is always null . But when i see the plan the filter is adding to the cost of the query.

Can some body guide me how does this work??

Comment: Why are you wanting it to optimize the parts of the plan that yield 0% cost?

Comment: But anyhow it is executed. And Actually I have a bigger/actual query where similar filter is costing me 7%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query plans in SQL Server are stored and reused. There is no analysis done to figure out that the value of a variable really is a constant so SQL Server has to generate a plan that can be reused for all possible values of the variable.

The query plan you have in your example will actually not touch the table `EmailComments` since the Left Semi Join only checks for existence of at least one row and that row comes from the Constant Scan that returns one row when `@CommentedOnly` is null.

You can ask SQL Server to generate a new plan for each execution using `option recompile`. You will get a overhead of a compilation for each execution but the variable value is guaranteed to be what it is and that knowledge is used by the optimizer so in your example it will build a plan that only contains the Clustered Index Scan and the Top operator.

```
select top 5 * from journalemail je
where @CommentedOnly IS NULL OR je.ID IN (SELECT EmailID FROM EmailComments)
option (recompile)
```

Comment: The executed plan does not change even if i clean all the caches and use recompile option. Seems like the query optimizer can not do away with the filter.

Comment: Even if i use " select top 5 * from journalemail jewhere @CommentedOnly IS NULL option (recompile)" Filter is there in execution plan with Number of Executions = 1.

Comment: actually on server , the plan contains the clustered index scan and the top operator, but on my local same plan is generated. By any chance this kind of optimization feature is widows version/ sql version dependent??

Comment: @Mokchhya Yes it is. Have a look at [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the query plan, it doesn't claim to be aware of the null declaration at all -- it seems to look only at the query. Perhaps similar code in a stored procedure, which guaranteedly couples the set value with the query, would in fact get optimized. This analyzer may be leaving room open for uses of the query in other contexts where no such null has been set.